# through parameter determine subclass type , but get error " Use of undeclared type ". How can I do?

Tags: ios, swift

I am getting below error at this line `if vc is targetVC`

> "Use of undeclared type 'targetVC'"

```
func popToTargetController(_ targetVC: UIViewController) -> Bool {
    guard let currentNv = tabBar?.selectedViewController as? UINavigationController else{
        return false
    }
    for vc in currentNv.viewControllers {
        if vc is targetVC {
            currentNv.popToViewController(vc, animated: false)
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

I have declared class like MovieController inherit form `UIViewController`, and I want pass MovieController as parameter to this method.

I want to use like this:

```
class MovieController: UIViewController {
    ....
    ....
    let _ = someModel.popToTargetController(MovieController)
    ....
}
```

Comment: Is `targetVC` a `class` you have declared? Pretty certain that is not the case. You have to put a class after the `is`. Or do you actually want to write `if vc == targetVC`?

Comment: @ luk2302  Thanks for your help. I have  declared  class like MovieController inherit form  UIViewController, and I want pass MovieController as parameter to this method. ps: my english so so...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I *think* I see what you are trying to do here.

You are trying to find the `targetVC` in the navigation stack, so that you can pop all the VCs on top of the `targetVC`.

When you say `if vc is targetVC`, that makes sense in English. But what you really mean in terms of Swift, is to check that `vc` and `targetVC` are the same type of VC.

To fix this, you need to introduce a generic type:

```
func popToTargetController<T: UIViewController>(_ targetVCType: T.Type) -> Bool {
    guard let currentNv = tabBar?.selectedViewController as? UINavigationController else{
        return false
    }
    for vc in currentNv.viewControllers {
        if vc is T {
            currentNv.popToViewController(vc, animated: false)
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

And pass your `MovieController` like this:

```
popToTargetController(MovieController.self)
```

Comment: Thank you very much!!  You understand correctly about my question, and I have try, your answer is right. My english so-so, only can read, can not write...

Answer (score 0):

Updating answer from comment:

targetVC is not a type. Just your argument name.

```
func popToTargetController(_ targetVC:  MovieController) -> Bool {
    guard let currentNv = tabBar?.selectedViewController as? 
    UINavigationController else {
        return false
    }
    for vc in currentNv.viewControllers {
        if vc is MovieController {
            currentNv.popToViewController(vc, animated: false)
            return true
        }
    }

    return false
}
```

Comment: thank you,  I have declared class like MovieController inherit form UIViewController, and I want pass MovieController as parameter to this method, so I can not use UIViewController direct

Comment: Sorry, my english is so-so, I did not say it clearly
, I want to "targetVC" like generic type, because I have like MovieController, MovieController2, MovieController3..., and they are all inherit form UIViewController